# Can't open PDF from Outlook email

Tags: outlook, pdf, attachments

When I tap a PDF attachment in Outlook I get asked "Search for app in the store". If I click Yes, I get to a blank page in the store.

I tried tapping save and navigating to a folder but nothing ever gets saved.
I downloaded PDF Reader from the store but that didn't help.

All other attachments open fine - any idea how to get PDFs opening?

If I try opening a PDF from OneDrive I get asked which app (Adobe, Edge or Reader) and all work fine.

Thanks
Nokia 640XL + Windows 10

Comment: try using adobe reader. it works like charm

Comment: @RAMRAJ It is already mentioned in the question that he tried adobe reader. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Does this happen with every `PDF` files in your email or just one or two `PDF` files? Because this can happen if your PDF files are corrupted

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

Long-press on the attachment, you should see a menu with
"Open"
"Save"

Save the PDF you received where you want on your phone, then browse it from the phone explorer. I can open the file directly from the app (asks me which app I wanna use), but I guess that works as a workaround for you

Comment: ***I tried tapping save and navigating to a folder but nothing ever gets saved.*** The author said in his question that he already tried what you said i.e) saving the file. Please read the question fully and carefully before answering.

Answer (score 0):

The microsoft pdf reader app on Windows Phone is now replaced by Microsoft Edge. You have to use Microsoft Edge now to open pdf files.